# How to POST multiple requests with XML parser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to POST 3 requests within same class with XML parser. I can manage to do only one request at a time. When I POST multiple requests, it says Parser Error. This is how I tried.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:getAllFoodsURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSString *paramDataString = [NSString stringWithString:
                             @"<GetNames><DeviceId>1234</DeviceId><UserId>200</UserId></GetNames>"];

[req addValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *paramData = [paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[req setHTTPBody: paramData];   

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData=data;
    [data release];
}
```

I have used NSXMLParser delegates methods. After one request is completed(connection release), then I create another connection and do the same process for second request. 
But it doesnot work.

I want to know, how to manage multiple requests with NSXMLParser?
If you can give me a code example, its highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess NSThread is what you are looking for.

But I am not sure as I am not much aware about that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that NSXMLParser isn't involved in HTTP requests -- do you mean NSURLRequest instead? You'll need to make your requests separately, possibly using separate blocks, operations, or threads.

Once you've retrieved the data for each request, you'll need to use separate NSXMLParser objects for each. A single instance of NSXMLParser is tied to its XML data at initialization -- you can't reuse a parser. You can use the same delegate for all your xml parsers, and the delegate can use the first parameter to each of the xml parser delegate methods (i.e. `parser`) to know which parser is calling a given method.

Comment: Yes, I have used a single NSXMLParser(but not here in the code smale). If I use a separate parser objects for each request, is it OK? Thanks a lot, I'll try that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidelines. But how to use separate blocks/threads for each request? can u please give a small code sample, then I can carryout further work